# Django 1.8rc1 migrate not recreating tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm using Django 1.8rc1.  I made a change to some models and ran into an issue so I decided to back up and just recreate all of my models.  I'm in the early stages so a complete rebuild of the database is no issue.

After removing all the migration files in my app/migrations folder, I did a makemigrations, which showed that three new tables have to be created:

```
Migrations for 'track':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Milestone
    - Create model Project
    - Create model Task
```

But then the migrate doesn't do the create tables step for some reason.

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: auth, sessions, track, admin, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I would think deleting the migration files would remove the history of tables ever being created and would force Django to re-run the CREATE TABLE statements.  Any idea why it isn't?

Comment: Did you drop the entire database? Are there entries in the django_migrations table?

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing me to the django_migrations table.  I cleared that, then had to drop and recreate the database, and that worked.  Now I'm having a different issue with MRO on inheritance.. might have to make that a separate question...

Answer (score 1):

The resolution for me was to delete the migrations directory from the offending app, (and I did a mkdir migrations just in case it was required) and then reran:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

That worked great, and I could see that the tables were created.

Comment: Thanks -- this command has been helpful to me if I need to completely remove migration files: `find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround:

Delete the db.sqlite3 file from your project source folder and run the migrations again.

---

Sometimes, when you modify models and run migrations django doesn't apply it smoothly. Not an issue, you could use South from next time.

Answer (score 0):

Django will create history in `django_migrations`. You need to clean it first then use those commands to generate your tables.

So try to go to your database and find the table `django_migrations`. Delete all the rows which have `app` equals your app name. For example 
id    app         name                applied
20    track       0001_initial        2016-01-13 02:55:23

Then do a `makemigrations` & `migrate` should work.